# Celery apply_async get get called multiple times

Tags: python, django, celery, amazon-sqs

I have created a task

```
@app.task(bind=True, max_retries=1)
def notify_feedback(self, req_id):
    #some things
```

I have called this task from my view with a delay of 1 hour like

```
later = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
notify_feedback.apply_async((req_id,), eta=later)
```

When I checked the SQS Messages in Flight it has 1 count pending
after one hour this `notify_feedback` get called multiple times. Did any one encountered this kind of issue with celery?

celery- 4.1.0 is used

Comment: Do you have more than 1 worker in your celery?

Comment: Yes 3 workers but the function get called about 10 to 15 times

Comment: I had such issue with 2 workers. Please see my solution below.

Comment: What time zone are you using with celery?

Comment: using the UTC timezone

Answer (score 2):

I faced such issue as well, but I have delayed task more than for 1 hour.

When I set this in settings.py my I solved my issue.

`BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 86400}`

The visibility timeout defines the number of seconds to wait for the worker to acknowledge the task before the message is redelivered to another worker.

More details [there](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html#caveats).